# FROM clause with DO UPDATE in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a upsert query using CONFLICT. But I am facing issue on update part. Here is my query looks like.

```
INSERT INTO
   customers (name, email, city) 
   SELECT
      'jack',
      'jack@io' as email,
      city 
   FROM
      customers 
   where
      id = 1 
      ON CONFLICT(name) DO 
      update
      set
         email = cs.email 
      FROM
         (
            select
               email 
            from
               customers 
            where
               id = 1
         )
         as cs;
```

**following is query structure**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

**Erro i am getting**

```
syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: ... ON CONFLICT(name) DO update set email = cs.email FROM (sele...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub-select has the wrong structure.

If you need to update multiple columns, use a tuple assignment

```
INSERT INTOcustomers (name, email, city) 
SELECT 'jack',
       'jack@io' as email,
       city 
FROM customers 
where id = 1 
ON CONFLICT(name) DO 
  update set (email, other_col) = (select email, c2
                                   from customers 
                                   where id = 1)
```

Comment: @AashishVerma: then you should have said so in the question. It's usually not appreciated if you extend the scope of the question once you get an answer to the original question. See my edit for a solution